# What term would be used for words that are borrowed from Japanese and used in other languages?

Tags: meaning, words, kanji, katakana, loanwords

Many Japanese words are used in other languages, sushi, anime, karaoke, tsunami....
Is there a term to identify these words? I am familiar with terms such as 外来語 to indicate loanwords borrowed from other languages. What term would be used to indicate words borrowed from Japanese?

Comment: それって「日本語の質問」なんですかね・・・？

Comment: 「外来語」の対義語にあたる日本語（海外に輸出された日本語を指す日本語）を聞いておられるようなので日本語の質問ではないでしょうか。

Comment: it is a Japanese question.

Comment: I think the wording of the title has room for improvement, though.

Comment: I thought "anime" was itself borrowed from french "dessin animé" (cartoon, lit. "animated drawing")

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA: That is correct - to my understanding, it's either taken from a shortening of the English "animation" or: [from the "French *animé* "animated, lively, roused," from the same Latin source as English animate, likely via Probably taken into Japanese from a phrase such as *dessin animé* "cartoon," literally "animated design," with the adjective abstracted or mistaken, due to its position, as a noun."](https://www.etymonline.com/word/anime#etymonline_v_13456).

Comment: "dessin animé" is actually "animated drawing", not "animated design". (I understand you were just quoting.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I do not know of a monolectic term for that though there might exist one.

The polylectic term that should be understood by virtually all adult native Japanese speakers would be 「日本語{にほんご}からの借用語{しゃくようご}」.

By inserting 「[language name] + における」 in front of the term above, you can safely and unambiguously say "**word(s) borrowed from Japanese (used in [language name])**".  Thus, you can say:

「英語{えいご}における日本語からの借用語」,

「スワヒリ語における日本語からの借用語」, etc.

Comment: おおおおひさ！ Welcome back!  :D

Answer (score 7):

As said in l’électeur’s answer, it’s far more likely that you’d use some longer phrase to describe such a word.

However, it seems like there is some currency for the term 「外行語{がいこうご}」, born as a reversal of 外来語. It doesn’t show up as in option in my kanji completion list, and its usage seems fairly minimal, but it is intuitive enough (written, not so much verbally) and does seem to get used occasionally.

Comment: I was thinking this way too.